# Programatically changes jQuery Mobile’s Collapsible sets

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, collapsable

I have a collapsible sets with 7 elements. It works fine. When I try to change the header of the each collapsible items, it changes the header but removes the collapsible styles.

Did someone come across such issues??

[image]

please find my code below.

jQuery

```
$('#MonColHead').text("Monday "+pad2((dateArray[0].getMonth()+1))+"-"+pad2(dateArray[0].getDate()));
$('#collapReadOnlyProj').selectmenu('refresh');
```

The html

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="collapReadOnlyProj">

        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 id="MonColHead">Monday</h3>
            <table align="center">
                <tr><th>Hours</th><th>Minutes</th></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="number" name="name" id="name" value=""  /> </td><td><input type="number" name="name" id="name" value=""  /></td></tr>
            </table>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textarea">External Notes</label>
                <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" style="min-height:120px"></textarea>
            </div>  
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textarea">Internal Notes</label>
                <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" style="min-height:120px"></textarea>
            </div>  
        </div>


        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3 id="SunColHead">Sunday</h3>
            <table align="center">
                <tr><th>Hours</th><th>Minutes</th></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="number" name="name" id="name" value=""  /> </td><td><input type="number" name="name" id="name" value=""  /></td></tr>
            </table>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textarea">External Notes</label>
                <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" style="min-height:120px"></textarea>
            </div>  
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textarea">Internal Notes</label>
                <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" style="min-height:120px"></textarea>
            </div>  
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('#MonColHead').text("Monday "+pad2((dateArray[0].getMonth()+1))+"-"+pad2(dateArray[0].getDate()));
$('#collapReadOnlyProj').selectmenu('refresh');
```

try this

```
$('#MonColHead .ui-btn-text').text("Monday "+pad2((dateArray[0].getMonth()+1))+"-"+pad2(dateArray[0].getDate()));
```